# How to get css , javascript of a html element in a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I saw a slider in a website and I want to get the CSS and javascript of that element so I can use in my website. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: What's about the [inspector](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css) in the dev-tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read and use code from a website, you use an "Inspect Editor" which is integrated in the browser. An example of Firefox Inspect Editor:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector

There you can call up the HTML Editor and the Style Editor.

[image]